For $k$-algebras $B_1, \dots, B_n$, $\# \operatorname{Hom}_k( \prod_{i=1}^nB_i, \Omega) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n \# \operatorname{Hom}_k(B_i, \Omega)$?
Let $k$ be a field with $ k \subseteq \Omega$ a algebraically closed field. Let $B_1 , \dots, B_n$ be ( possibly finite local ) $k$-algebras. Then next equality of cardinals holds
$$ \# \operatorname{Hom}_k( \prod_{i=1}^nB_i, \Omega) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n \# \operatorname{Hom}_k(B_i, \Omega)$$
?
We can refer to the Rotman's An introduction to Homological Algebra, Theorem 2.31 so that
$$ \operatorname{Hom}_k( \prod_{i=1}^nB_i, \Omega)  \cong \prod_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Hom}_k(B_i , \Omega)$$
Then,  $$ \# \prod_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Hom}_k(B_i , \Omega) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n \# \operatorname{Hom}_k(B_i, \Omega) $$ ?
This question originates from second question of next linked question : Understanding the Proposition 12.18 in Gortz's Algebraic Geometry. In the linked question I don't know whether the equality marked by question symbol - in procedure of deriving the second equality - is true ; i.e., $ \# \operatorname{Hom}_{k'} (\prod_{i=1}^{n}B_{\mathfrak{p}_{x_i'}} , \Omega) \overset{\mathrm{?}}{=} \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}\#\operatorname{Hom}_{k'}(B_{\mathfrak{p}_{x_i'}}, \Omega)$.  An issue that makes me stuck is, the cardinal of finite product of sets is the product of cardinals of each sets, not the sum. Am I missing something?

Your context is not an additive category, so the result from Rotman doesn't apply

But $#\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\prod_{i=1}^n#X_i$ for sure, so that's also a mistake

You can use \sum to produce the correct sized symbol for summation.

@Asaf Karagila : Ah~ O.K. Thanks ~

Your first statement is correct: in fact, it is true that:
$$\hom\left(\prod_{i=1}^nB_i,\Omega\right)=\coprod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega).$$
You can see this as follows: pick any morphism $\phi \in \hom\left(\prod_{i=1}^nB_i,\Omega\right)$, and let $e_i = (0,...,1,...,0) \in \prod_{i=1}^nB_i$ (a 1 on the $i$-th component). The $(e_i)$ form a complete set of nontrivial orthogonal idempotents of $\prod_{i=1}^nB_i$, i.e. they satisfy:

$e_i^2 = e_i$
$e_i e_j = 0$ if $i \neq j$
$\sum_i e_i = 1$
$e_i$ is neither 0 nor 1 in $\prod_{i=1}^nB_i$

Now notice that the images $\phi(e_i)$ do also satisfy the three first conditions, but the only way for this to happen is that one of the $\phi(e_i)$ is one, and the other $\phi(e_j)$ are all zero (there are no nontrivial idempotents in $\Omega$). In particular, this shows that $\phi$ factors as:
$$\prod_{i=1}^nB_i \xrightarrow{\phi} B_i \rightarrow \Omega$$
This defines a map $\hom\left(\prod_{i=1}^nB_i,\Omega\right) \rightarrow \coprod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega)$, which is easily seen to be a bijection.
You are actually not quoting Rotman's statement quite right: the actual isomorphism is
$$\hom\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^nB_i,\Omega\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega)$$
and in the context of $k$-algebras (or more generally, commutative rings), direct sums (tensor products) are very different from products.
As mentionned by FShrike below, if $k$-algebras were an abelian category, finite products and coproducts would be canonically isomorphic, and the original (wrong) statement would be correct. This is what happens for groups, or modules over a ring.

It help for op to mention (i) my own mistake of forgetting that of course $k$-algebras don't form an additive category, so the result doesn't apply and (ii) explicitly, if $\phi(e_i)=1=\phi(e_j)$ for $i\neq j$ then $\phi(e_ie_j)=0=1\cdot1$ is a contradiction, since they seemed confused in comments. Thanks for catching that; I've been doing too much hom. alg., "everything is additive"

I don't understand your construction $\Psi : \hom\left(\prod_{i=1}^nB_i,\Omega\right) \rightarrow \coprod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega)$ at all until now. Let me follow your construction. Fix $\phi : \prod_{=1}^n B_i \to \Omega$. As you said, $\phi(e_i)=1 $, $\phi(e_j)=0$ for all $j \neq i$. Assume that $\phi(e_1)=1 $, $\phi(e_j)=0$ for all $j \neq 1$. Then does there exists $f_1 : B_1 \to \Omega$ such that
for $(b_i)= (b_1 , \dots b_n) \in B := \prod_{i=1}^n B_i$, $\phi((b_i))= f_1 \circ pr_1 ((b_i))$, where $pr_1 : B \to B_1$ is the projection ?

If so, we define $\Psi(\phi) := (f_1,1) \in \coprod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega) $. Am I following well?  And if so, how can we take such $f_1 :B_1 \to \Omega$ more explicitly?

That's right, $f_1$ is simply defined by the fact that $\phi$ is equal to $\phi \circ (\operatorname{id} \times 0 \times ... \times 0)$ (i.e. $\phi$ only reads one coordinate), so $\phi$ factors through $B_1 \times {0} \times ... \times {0}$ which is obviously isomorphic to $B_1$. And in that case, the corresponding element of $\coprod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega)$ (which is the disjoint union of all $\hom(B_i,\Omega)$) is the corresponding map in $\hom(B_1,\Omega)$

If you denote by $\iota_1 : B_1 \rightarrow B_1 \times {0} \times ... \times {0}$ the isomorphism, then $\Psi : \hom\left(\prod_{i=1}^nB_i,\Omega\right) \rightarrow \coprod_{i=1}^n\hom(B_i,\Omega)$ is defined as: $\Psi (\phi) = \phi \circ \iota_1$. But it is better to "feel" the situation rather than to make every single correspondance explicit (although I agree that it is reassuring).

O.K. Brilliance. 1)  Considering its domain and codomain, more correct definition is $\Psi( \phi): = \phi \circ ( id_{B_1} \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0 ) \circ \iota_1$. 2) And I am struggling to show that $\phi = \phi \circ  ( id_{B_1} \times 0 \times \cdots \times 0 ) \circ \iota_1 \circ \operatorname{pr}_1 $ (more correct form regarding its domain and codomain) rigorously from $\phi(e_1)=1$, $\phi(e_j)=0$ for all $j\neq 1$ ; i.e., $\phi((b_1, \dots , b_n))= \phi ( ( b_1 , 0 , \dots ,0 ))$ (?) Can you teach me about this more in detail? Please understand my speed of understanding.

All you need is the observation that for any $b \in \prod_{i=1}^nB_i$, $b = b \times 1= \sum_i b e_i$ (because the $e_i$ for a complete set of nontrivial indempotents). Then apply $\phi$. Then write explicitely who $b e_i$ is in terms of coordinates.

Wow, O.K. Thanks for pointing out key point. I got it. Thank you. ( P.s. How could you think such an idea of the answer ? )

There is no magic mind involved, this is just similar to some techniques I am working with these days. From my experience, the vast majority of maths skills are developed gradually over time, by "getting used to" reading techniques that you couln't have thought about yourself. The more you use them, the more likely you will spontaneously think about them elsewhere. There is no way a single person can discover alone the whole ocean of tricks that are used everywhere.

Oh, O.K. I will refer. Thanks for advice  !
